# Directing iframe search hits to parent site

Tags: google-search, iframe

We have created a campaign site that will be embedded into the customer's Sharepoint site as an iframe. We don't want people to access our site directly, and would like to make the search results point to the customer's parent site containing the iframe instead. Is this possible?

Comment: What problems have you come across? You could just append any request data to the Iframe query string, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly (as tagged with `google-search`), you want search results from Google to point to your customer's site that contains an iFrame, instead of your site from which the iFrame originates.

As stated [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34445?hl=en):

> Google tries to associate framed content with the page containing the
>   frames, but we don't guarantee that we will.

As also indicated there, you can use the [noframes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noframes.asp) tag (*not supported in HTML5*) to provide alternative content that search engines can use to index the iFrame with.

[IFrames](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) also support [Global Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp), including the [title](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp) attribute which can be used to add keywords for the iFrame, just like anchor text in a link. You can also add them to a longer description in the [longdesc](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_longdesc.asp) attribute (*also not supported in HTML5*). Using these attributes may also help get the iFrame indexed on the customer's page.

You should also add a [canonical URL](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en) in the page on your site that points to the customer's page so that search engines might consider that as the page to index, and you should add a disallow directive in your *robots.txt* file to tell robots not to index the URL of the page on your site.

Combing the above with additional content on the customer's page that's relevant to the terms that search engine users might search for, will improve your chances that your customer's page will be indexed and found in searches.